# How to add extra field to Algolia

Tags: reactjs, algolia, contentful

I have a already made project having connection between **Algolia + Gatsby + Contentful**.
In which the algolia queries have

```
  allContentfulProduct {
    nodes {
      objectID: id
      productTitle: title
      slug
      seoTitle
      node_locale
    }
  }
}
const queries = [
  {
    indexName: process.env.ALGOLIA_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME_PRODUCTS,
    query,
    transformer: ({ data }) => data.allContentfulProduct.nodes,
  }
]
```

I need to add one extra field to algolia to filter through the search.
But when i add `isVisibleInternalSearch` to the `const query` the field is only visible when the gatsby build command in ran.

When there is any change in the contenful fields then the site is not able to find the algolia field.

```
  allContentfulProduct {
    nodes {
      objectID: id
      productTitle: title
      slug
      seoTitle
      node_locale
      isVisibleInternalSearch
    }
  }
}
```

I am having the same problem in the example site I created on netlify. Once the site was working fine but when there was any kind of change in contentful the field from the algolia disappeared.

Comment: Hey Varanshu — are you rebuilding the site via a webhook when you update entries in Contentful? I use Algolia for my search on my website, and in order to add new entries, I use a webhook to trigger a rebuild which then runs my Algolia build script.

Comment: @whitep4nth3r could you please explain a bit what do you mean about using webhook to trigger a rebuild to run Algolia build script.

Comment: I have a postbuild script which is defined in package.json. This is a script that runs to fetch my data from Contentful, process it for Algolia, and send it to Algolia. In order to fetch new data from Contentful and send it to Algolia, the site will need to be rebuilt after an entry is published (you can do this via a Webhook), after which the postbuild script will run, sending the new data from Contentful to Algolia. Unless I am misunderstanding your issue?